# Phonegap Android with PushPlugin compilation failure

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to run a phonegap application with the PushPlugin installed.
I adde the plugin with this command:

```
$ phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin
```

and it went through ok.
I added the PushNotification.js file to my "www" folder and referenced it in index.html.
Then I added some code to handle notifications in my index.js file.
I tried to run the application:

```
$ phonegap local run android
```

and got this:

```
-compile:
[javac] Compiling 8 source files to /Users/nadavelyashiv/Code/PushNotificationSample/platforms/android/bin/classes
[javac] /Users/nadavelyashiv/Code/PushNotificationSample/platforms/android/src/com/plugin/gcm/GCMIntentService.java:96: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : method getString(java.lang.String)
[javac] location: class com.plugin.gcm.GCMIntentService
[javac]                 .setTicker(getString("title"))
[javac]                            ^
[javac] /Users/nadavelyashiv/Code/PushNotificationSample/platforms/android/src/com/plugin/gcm/GCMIntentService.java:95: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : method getString(java.lang.String)
[javac] location: class com.plugin.gcm.GCMIntentService
[javac]                 .setContentTitle(getString("title"))
[javac]                                  ^
[javac] 2 errors
BUILD FAILED
/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/r22.0.4/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/r22.0.4/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

What seems to be the problem here?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found issue, created a PullRequest on project :

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/pull/83/files

You should update the code of line 95 and 96 of android/com/plugin/gcm/GCMIntentService.java

```
            .setContentTitle(extras.getString("title"))
            .setTicker(extras.getString("title"))
```